# is there a simple way to add the dplyr summarize function result to every row?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

The following is a simple version of my data:

[image: sample dataset]

I want to create a flag for each group if they at least have one item in Column1. 
I know I can do this in dplyr and then merge it with my original data but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

For example, I can do this:

```
df_column <- df %>% filter(!is.na(Column1)) %>% group_by(Group)%>%
  summarize(n=n_distinct(Column1))
```

and then I can merge this with the original data and create a flag.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Don't post data as images because we can't copy/paste it to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `filter`ing, we can do this with `mutate` by creating a logical column based on the number of unique elements (`n_distinct`) in 'Column1' after groupingby 'Group'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Group) %>%
     mutate(flag = n_distinct(Column1[!is.na(Column1)]) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a riff on the previous answer using `ifelse` which may be easier to understand if you're coming from Excel (which it looks like you may be):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(flag = ifelse(
        is.na(column1),
        "flag",
        "dont_flag"
    ))
```